What material is this indoor sill made of?
This is an interior stool at one of my windows. Some windows have it, some don't. I am handy and have tools to make window stools, so I'd like to make the missing ones for the house. I am not sure what material this is made of, though. It for sure isn't vinyl or any other form of plastic. It might be MDF or some hardwood. It feels harder than MDF to touch, though. Also MDF could swell if it rains on it, so I would think that they didn't choose MDF back when they built the house. Any idea what it could be?
Also, when I make new ones, how do I attach them? Do I caulk and nail a few brad nails through into the wood under the corner bead?
Thanks!

I am trying to add a stool to this window:


MDF will swell if it gets wet.  If it well sealed it won't get wet.  It will hard to tell what it is, unless you remove the paint/cut a piece off.  The right hand looks a bit rough, but rough wood or bad paint job.

It looks like a 1x4 wood.  The grain showing and you stating that it is hard, indicates it may be oak.

When we finished two bedrooms in the basement a few years ago, I trimmed out the windows with PVC board, like this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Metrie-PVC-Trim-Board-3-4-In-x-3-1-2-In-x-8-Ft/5013353133.  I didn't want to deal with water damage from a window that got left open with the sprinklers on or with rain.

@spuck. Thanks! That looks fine, but wouldn't match the other existing stools. Those  are wooden. So I think I'll go with a painted pine.

I have gone through many a home in the US and have not once seen MDF used as a window stool.  The window sill is below the window and is considered exterior trim and the window stool is the trimwork on the interior of the house.
This also looks to have grain.   Most sills are oak or pine.     If I were to guess I would say this is pine because I don't see any deeper grains.  But with the grain pattern it could be PVC (it isn't but most PVC have faux grains).
Adding a window stool can be added to any window however the depth of the window (inset to the wall) is really a key factor.
Two common cases:

The window in the picture above having a 2-3" inset.   This allows you a place to secure the window stool so it does not "tip over" or become loose when someone leans on it.   From fixing up older homes I can tell you that if a window is low people will step on it and if a window is higher they will set things on it and hit it.   Installing a stool with an inset window is quite easy and if we are doing this at a house we generally just try to match the existing window stools (if they have any).

Window has a very small inset or is "flat to the wall.   Generally we try not to add stools to these but I understand if you have 1-2 windows that don't and the others do trying to match them.   Here we would install a flatter trim piece below the window on the interior.   This would be used to help secure the window stool.   You would have to make this a very small stool - maybe matching how far the other ones stick out.



Thank you! Very informative. I guess the stool is a pine or oak. I'd opt for oak - seems like a higher quality. I am going to add a picture to the post to show you an example of a window where I need to install the missing stool. The inset is very small, like you said. And yes, the other stools have a trim piece below. I'd do the same. Do you have any recommendation on how to properly attach the stool? I am thinking a combination of a painter's caulk and brad nails? Thanks a lot!

@pkout  Oak is nice if you are wanting to stain it or is under abusive(stepping on) conditions.  Painting it or for windows, oak is not needed and kind of expensive.

@pkout - oak is the superior wood but tends to look terrible painted.    If painted you go pine.
